# How can I escape some special characters in Jquery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm made some modifications in an e-commerce platform and I can't select an attribute.

```
 $('.menu.superior a[title=E-LIQUID'S / JUICE]')
```

However, the whitespace, the quote (') and the "/", are throwing an exception...

How Can I escape these characters? I've tried with "\", but it didn't work.

Comment: `$('.menu.superior a[title="E-LIQUID'S / JUICE"]')` — quote the attribute value. I would offer the suggestion that building code based on content like the "title" attribute is *probably* a really bad idea in the long run.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.escapeSelector/

Comment: Use double-quotes?

Comment: Plural of e-liquid is e-liquids...

Comment: You also need to escape the embedded single quote with backslash.

Comment: Do you *really* need to select elements by their `title` attribute?

Comment: Yes @Bergi, because, I haven't control of the platformand the title is the only element that differentiates the elements

Answer (score 3):

Alternate approach that is a bit more verbose but doesn't require escaping is to use `filter(function)`

```
$('.menu.superior a[title]').filter(function(){
   return this.title === "E-LIQUID'S";
});
```

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl! With yout solution I have managed to make it work

Answer (score 2):

Quote the attribute value, and escape the single quote so it doesn't terminate the string.

```
$('.menu.superior a[title="E-LIQUID\'S / JUICE"]')
```